# How do we test interactor organizers using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, interactors

I want to test below organizer interactor for, calling the 2 specified interactors without executing the calling interactors('SaveRecord, PushToService') code.

```
class Create
  include Interactor::Organizer

  organize SaveRecord, PushToService
end
```

I found few examples where the overall result of all the interactors logic(record should be saved and pushed to other service) has been tested. But, i dont want to execute the other interactor's logic as they will be tested as part of their separate specs.

```
1. Is it possible to do so?
2. Which way of testing(testing the overall result/testing only this particular 
   organizer interactor behavior) is a better practise?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe we need to test the interactor organizer for included interactors without executing the included interacors. I am able to find a way stub and test the organizer with below lines

To Stub:

```
  allow(SaveRecord).to receive(:call!) { :success }
  allow(PushToService).to receive(:call!) { :success }
```

To Test:

```
it { expect(interactor).to be_kind_of(Interactor::Organizer) }
it { expect(described_class.organized).to eq([SaveRecord, PushToService]) }
```

Found `call! method & organized variable` from interactor organizer source files where it is trying to call and use internally. Stubbing the `call!` method and testing the `organized` variable has fulfilled my requirement.

Comment: If anyone looking at this would like some additional examples, the Interactor README now has some:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor#testing-interactors

Comment: how is `interactor` define?

Answer (score 3):

You can test they are called and the order:

```
it 'calls the interactors' do
  expect(SaveRecord).to receive(:call!).ordered
  expect(PushToService).to receive(:call!).ordered
  described_class.call
end
```

See: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/message-order

Answer (score 1):

Just iterating over [@prem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524740/prem) answer.

> To Test:
>
> ```rb
> it { expect(interactor).to be_kind_of(Interactor::Organizer) }
> it { expect(described_class.organized).to eq([SaveRecord, PushToService]) }
> ```

`interactor` in this case is an instance of the Interactor class, or in Rspec syntax:

```rb
let(:interactor) { described_class.new }
```